# positioning flash content using css

Tags: html, css, flash

I am designing a website which will have four hover buttons in the corners and flash content in the middle:

[image]

I am using the following code for the buttons which works fine:

HTML:

```
div.container { position:relative; }
img.positioned { position:absolute; height:63px; width:122px; }
img#topleft { top:0; left:0; }
img#topright { top:0; right:0; }
img#bottomleft { bottom:0; left:0; }
img#bottomright { bottom:0; right:0; }
```

CSS:

```
<div class="container">
<img src="image.gif" class="positioned" id="topleft">
<img src="image.gif" class="positioned" id="topright">
<img src="image.gif" class="positioned" id="bottomleft">
<img src="image.gif" class="positioned" id="bottomright">
</div>
```

But I am having difficulty positioning the flash content.

What would be the correct html and css code to position the 4 buttons with a hover effect and the flash content.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Flash content is of fixed dimensions, you first put that into a div then use absolute positioning to 50% and negative margins.  Let's assume that your Flash content is 300x200.

HTML:

```
<div id="flashContainer">
    <object width="300" height="200" ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#flashContainer {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px; /* half the width and height values */
}
```